# Conversion fails when running stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Aloha,

I have a stored procedure that looks in 3 different columns for a value.

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CLAIMS_QUERY_FAC_]

  @sPLAN  varchar(5),
  @sTYPE  varchar(3),
  @nVALUE varchar(10) ,
  @begDOS date,
  @endDOS date

 AS
 BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

 -- QUERY BASED ON CAID.............................................................
 IF @sPLAN = 'CAID'
   IF @sTYPE = 'MBR'
       BEGIN
SELECT  DISTINCT
PLN, DH, PT, PROVIDER, TAX, PROV_NAME,  MEMGRP, MEMSUB, MBR_NAME,
POS, AUDNBR, CLM_ADJ, LN_NR, RCVD_DT, FIRST_DOS, LAST_DOS, CPT, CPT_MOD, 
UNITS, DIAG1, PAID_DT, REV_CDE, BILL_TYPE, FIN_LGL_NBR, PAR, OCC_CD5,
AMT_CLAIMED, AMT_DISALLOW, AMT_DISCOUNT, AMT_DEDUCT, AMT_COPAY, AMT_PAID,
DEN_CDE, DSLW_CDE, DENY_DESC, DSLW_DESC, ADJ_RSN_DESC, REV_DESC, POS_DESC, 
CPT_DESC, DIAG_DESC
FROM v_QI_CLAIMS_FAC
WHERE (@nVALUE  = (MEME_HICN) AND (FIRST_DOS BETWEEN @begDOS AND @endDOS) AND PLN = 'CAID')
OR (@nVALUE = (MEMSUB) AND (FIRST_DOS BETWEEN @begDOS AND @endDOS) AND PLN = 'CAID')
OR (@nVALUE = (MEME_CK) AND (FIRST_DOS BETWEEN @begDOS AND @endDOS) AND PLN = 'CAID')
     ORDER BY AUDNBR, LN_NR, CLM_ADJ
    END
```

The data in the memsub and meme_hicn are varchar in the table, meme_ck is an int. The query pulls data okay for memsub and meme_ck, but when the value comes from meme_hicn I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '558901488A' to data type int (where the data value is '558901488A'.

It looks like it is interpreting meme_hicn as an int, but it should be as a varchar.

I have tried all sorts of options, cast, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You mentioned that `MEME_CK` is an `INT`, but you have `@nVALUE = (MEME_CK)`, and `@nVALUE` is a `VARCHAR`.  Try using `@nVALUE = Convert(Varchar (10), MEME_CK)`.

Comment: OMG, I never thought about converting MEME_CK because it returned values for that field okay. I am guessing it is because once it read MEME_CK as an INT it automatically treated MEME_HICN as an INT also. Thanks so much!!

Comment: @Kimo, anytime you have an implicit conversion with a varchar and an int the database engine will try to convert both sides to an int.